# Convert cypher "WHERE IN" clause to Neo4JClient

Tags: c#, neo4jclient

How would I convert the following cyper query to Neo4JClient

```
MATCH (user:User),(interest:Interest)
WHERE interest.Id IN [2,4,9,17] AND user.Id = 46
CREATE user-[rel:INTERESTED_IN]->interest
RETURN rel
```

What I have done is

```
await graphClient.Cypher
             .Match("(interest:Interest)", "(user:User)")
             .Where((Interest interest) => interests.Contains(interest.Id))
             .AndWhere((User user) => user.Id == userData)
             .CreateUnique("user-[INTERESTED_IN]->interest")
            .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

> userData and interests are variables defined earlier in the method

My code throws the following exception

```
SyntaxException: Invalid input 't' (line 2, column 13)
"WHERE {p0}interest.Id
"
         ^
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `userData` is an `int`, I would suggest trying this

```
var userData = 46;
var interestIds = new[] { 2, 4, 9, 17 };

await _client.Cypher
    .Match("(interest:Interest), (user:User)")
    .Where((User user) => user.Id == userData)
    .AndWhere("interest.Id IN {interestIds}")
    .WithParams(new { interestIds })
    .ExecuteWithoutResultsAsync();
```

It might be easier to write the Cypher for the `IN` predicate as opposed to writing them into C# that then gets translated back. This is then parameterised, which according to the [Neo4jClient documentation](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/cypher#parameters):

> Cypher parameters are the safe way to inject dynamic information into queries. They avoid the risk of injection based attacks, and ensure that your values are accurately encoded.
>
> They also significantly improve query plan caching on the Neo4j side, because the query text doesn't change so Neo4j doesn't have to recompile the plan on every hit.

Also note that this is not a direct translation of your original Cypher query since it does not return the created relationship(s).

Comment: Yes userData is an int and yes this looks like it would solve my problem, will mark as answer as soon as I am able to test. Thanks